# stub file in client class not recocgnised using soap

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I followed this guide "http://wso2.com/library/1719/", I didn't modified nothig except in the part of java to wsdl where i setted the taget namespace as

> http ://ws

and in schema target namespace

> http ://ws

I used for this tutorial a service and a client. I generate correctly (the tomcat server doesn't give error in axis page) the.aar file and the wsdl from it.

Service:

`

```java
import java.time.*;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ATMachine {
//program begin

    public double deposita(double amount) {    
        Deposit.deposit = amount; //= read.nextDouble();
        BalanceInquiry.balance = Deposit.deposit + BalanceInquiry.getBalance();
        LocalDateTime date1= LocalDateTime.now();
        String md= "deposit";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy     HH:mm:ss");
    String date2= date1.format(formatter);
        BalanceInquiry.updateBalance(Deposit.deposit,BalanceInquiry.movement,md,date2);
        return Deposit.deposit;     
    }

    public double preleva(double amount) {        
        Withdraw.withdraw = amount;
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
        String mw= "withdraw";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss");
        String date3= date.format(formatter);
      BalanceInquiry.updateBalance(Withdraw.withdraw,BalanceInquiry.movement,mw,date3);
    int erwithdraw=BalanceInquiry.withdrawMoney(); // risposta di withdraw
    return erwithdraw;
    }

    public String[] bilancio(){
        double  checkb=BalanceInquiry.getBalance();
        String[] rbilancio= new String[12];
        rbilancio[0]= Double.toHexString(checkb);
        for(int i1=1;i1<=rbilancio.length;i1++){
            for(int i=0;i<= BalanceInquiry.movement.length-1; i++){
                if(BalanceInquiry.movement[i]==null){
                    rbilancio[i1]="";
                }
                else{rbilancio[i1]=BalanceInquiry.movement[i];
                }   
            }
        }
    return rbilancio;      
    }     
}
```

`

ATMClient
`

```java
package ws;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.axis2.description.PolicyInclude;
import org.apache.neethi.Policy;
import org.apache.rampart.policy.model.CryptoConfig;
import org.apache.rampart.policy.model.RampartConfig;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;

public class ATMClient {

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
double amount=0;
int select = 0;
int choice = 0;
//To be able to load the client configuration from axis2.xml

//ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("axis-repo",null);
    ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("axis-repo", "axis-repo\\conf\\axis2.xml");

    ATMachineStub stub = new ATMachineStub(ctx,"http://localhost:8888/axis2/services/ATMachine");

    ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();

    sc.engageModule("rampart");

System.out.println("====================================================");
System.out.println("\tWelcome to this simple ATM machine");
System.out.println("====================================================");
System.out.println();

do
{try
        {
    do {

            System.out.println("\tPlease select ATM Transactions");
            System.out.println("\tPress [1] Deposit");
            System.out.println("\tPress [2] Withdraw");
            System.out.println("\tPress [3] Balance Inquiry");
            System.out.println("\tPress [4] Exit");

            System.out.print("\n\tWhat would you like to do? ");
            select = read.nextInt();

                if(select>4)
                {
                    System.out.println("\n\tPlease select correct transaction.");
                }
                else
                {
                switch (select)
                {
                    case 1:
                        amount=0;
                        System.out.print("\n\tEnter the amount of money to deposit: ");
                        amount= read.nextDouble();
                        double result= stub.deposita(amount);
                        System.out.println("\tYou deposited the amount of " + amount);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        amount=0;
                        System.out.print("\n\tTo withdraw, make sure that you have sufficient balance in your account.");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.print("\tEnter amount of money to withdraw: ");
                        amount= read.nextDouble();
                        double erpreleva=stub.preleva(amount);
                        if(erpreleva==1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("\tYour current balance is zero.");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cannot withdraw!");
                            System.out.println("\tYou need to deposit money first.");
                        }

                        else if(erpreleva==2)
                        {
                            System.out.println("\tThe amount you withdraw is greater than to your balance");
                            System.out.println("\tPlease check the amount you entered.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("\n\tYou withdraw the amount of Php " + amount);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        String[] bilanciores= new String[12];
                        bilanciores=stub.bilancio();
                        System.out.println("\tYour current balance is:" + bilanciores[0]);
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("\tThe last 10 operation are:\n ");
                        for(int i=1;i<bilanciores.length;i++){
                            System.out.println("\t"+ bilanciores[i] +"\n");
                            }
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.print("\n\tTransaction exited.");
                        break;

                }
            }               

    }while(select>4);

    do {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("\n\tWould you like to try another transaction?");
            System.out.println("\n\tPress [1] Yes \n\tPress [2] No");
            System.out.print("\tEnter choice: ");
            choice = read.nextInt();

                if(choice>2)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\tPlease select correct choice.");
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\tError Input! Please enter a number only.");
                read = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\tEnter yout choice:");
                choice = read.nextInt();
            }
    } while(choice>2);
}
catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\tError Input! Please enter a number only.");
            read = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("\tEnter yout choice:");
            select = read.nextInt();
        }

}while(choice<=1);

System.out.println("\n\tThank you for using this simple ATM Machine.");
} 
}
```

`

The classes BalanceInquiry, Deposit, Withdraw have get and response methods and works.

All the declared libraries are added to the project.
But in ATMClient Eclipse says

> ATMachineStub cannot be resolved to a type

I also tried to create an interface with the wizard using instead that ws and ws, ws and ws/xsd but cause error on the methods bilancio(), deposita(), and preleva() requiring to modify the parameters in the ATMchineStub file froma deposita(Deposita) to deposita(double), (the same for the other methods).
 I post also the xml file of the wsdl :

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
    <wsdl:documentation>ATMachine</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.apache.org/axis2">
            <xs:element name="deposita">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amount" type="xs:double"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="depositaResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:double"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="preleva">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amount" type="xs:double"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="prelevaResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:double"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="bilancioResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="bilancioRequest"/>
    <wsdl:message name="bilancioResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:bilancioResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="prelevaRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:preleva"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="prelevaResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:prelevaResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="depositaRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:deposita"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="depositaResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:depositaResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ATMachinePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="bilancio">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:bilancioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:bilancio"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:bilancioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:bilancioResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="preleva">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:prelevaRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:preleva"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:prelevaResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:prelevaResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="deposita">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:depositaRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:deposita"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:depositaResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:depositaResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ATMachineSoap11Binding" type="ns:ATMachinePortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="bilancio">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:bilancio" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="preleva">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:preleva" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="deposita">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:deposita" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="ATMachineSoap12Binding" type="ns:ATMachinePortType">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="bilancio">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:bilancio" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="preleva">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:preleva" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="deposita">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:deposita" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="ATMachineHttpBinding" type="ns:ATMachinePortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="bilancio">
            <http:operation location="ATMachine/bilancio"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="bilancio"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="bilancio"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="preleva">
            <http:operation location="ATMachine/preleva"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="preleva"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="preleva"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="deposita">
            <http:operation location="ATMachine/deposita"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="deposita"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="deposita"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ATMachine">
        <wsdl:port name="ATMachineHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:ATMachineSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ATMachine.ATMachineHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ATMachineHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:ATMachineSoap12Binding">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ATMachine.ATMachineHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ATMachineHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:ATMachineHttpBinding">
            <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ATMachine.ATMachineHttpEndpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>`

Can somebody suggest me how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using WSS4J by terminal. Instead of the eclipse service it has solved.